# How can I call a function using parameter list in c++?

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing, call

I have a unchangeable function like

```
void foo(int a, const char* b, int c)
{
}
```

and I want to call this function as follows:

```
void main()
{
    paramList.add(1);//adding int
    paramList.add("hello world"); //adding string
    paramList.add(3);//adding int
    foo(paramlist);

}
```

How can I call foo function as in example?

Comment: What's `paramList`? Is it a `std::list`? This example doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an overloaded function that takes the `paramlist` object, and extracts the items to call the proper `foo` function with its actual arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. No matter what tricks you try to pull off in the calling code, the function must be passed three arguments.

What you probably have in mind *does* exist in C++ and is known as the [Named Parameter Idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-parameter-idiom). But it would require changing the function which you are describing as "unchangeable."

---

P.S.: `void main` is not legal C++. Make it `int main`.